# twitter bootstrap - icon in search form disappears after selecting form

Tags: css, forms, search, twitter-bootstrap, icons

I am using twitter bootstrap and want to have a search icon inside the search field. I managed to get it working, however when selecting the form, for some reason the icon disappears. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="control-group">
<div class="form-controls">

<div class="input-append">
<span class="fornav"><i class="icon-search"></i></span><input type="text" class="search-query span2" placeholder="Search&hellip;">
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.fornav {
     position:relative;
    margin-right:-22px;
    top:-3px;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Thank you very much for any advice :)

Comment: What icon do you mean.. ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. I changed z-index to 9999 and it works :)